# How to use @Loader with positional parameters in hibernate?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, orm

I am trying to use @Loader annotation to populate the collection by query using hibernate.

Suppose I have a Menu class which contains List of submenus. I want these submenus to be populated using @NamedNativeQuery.

The problem is that when i put the positional parameters in query, i don't know how to set it's value at run time?

Here is my Menu class. When I fetch the menus, all the submenus are null. where should I set the positional parameter value? Can you please help?

Here is my XML

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

    <hibernate-mapping>  
   <sql-query name="getMenus">
        <load-collection alias="menu" role="com.pmc.domain.Menu.submenus" />
        select 
            {menu.*}
        from
            Menu menu
        join menu_roles mr on (mr.menu_item_id=menu.menu_item_id)
        join roles r on (r.user_role_id=mr.user_role_id)
        join user_roles ur on (ur.user_role_id=r.user_role_id)
        join users u on (u.username = ur.username)
        where 
            menu.parent = ? and u.username=?

    </sql-query>

    </hibernate-mapping>
```

And here is my POJO.

```
package com.pmc.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Filter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Loader;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;

@Entity
@Table(name="menu", catalog="test")
public class Menu implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "menu_item_id")
    private Integer menuId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="MENU_ROLES",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="menu_item_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_role_id")})
    private List<UserRole> userRoles;
    @Column(name = "label", length = 100)
    private String label;
    @Column(name = "link", length = 100)
    private String link;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
    private Menu parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Loader(namedQuery = "getMenus")
    private List<Menu> submenus;


    public Integer getMenuId() {
        return menuId;
    }
    public void setMenuId(Integer menuId) {
        this.menuId = menuId;
    }

    public List<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }
    public void setUserRoles(List<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
    public Menu getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Menu parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public List<Menu> getSubmenus() {
        return submenus;
    }
    public void setSubmenus(List<Menu> submenus) {
        this.submenus = submenus;
    }



}
```

This is my DAO method

```
public List<Menu> getMenus() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         Query query =   session.getNamedQuery("getMenus");
        query=query.setParameter(0, 1);
        query=query.setParameter(1, "jigar");
        List<Menu> menuList = session.createQuery("select menu from User user, IN (user.userRole) roles, IN(roles.menus) menu where user.username = 'jigar' and menu.parent=0").list();
        return menuList;
    }
```

When I call getMenus, it returns list of menus. but when they are accessed at jsp, submenu query results in an exception below

```
Expected positional parameter count: 2, actual parameters: [1] [select 
        {menu.*}
    from
        Menu menu
    join menu_roles mr on (mr.menu_item_id=menu.menu_item_id)
    join roles r on (r.user_role_id=mr.user_role_id)
    join user_roles ur on (ur.user_role_id=r.user_role_id)
    join users u on (u.username = ur.username)
    where 
        menu.parent = ? and u.username=?]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:429)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.verifyParameters(SQLQueryImpl.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:134)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.NamedQueryCollectionInitializer.initialize(NamedQueryCollectionInitializer.java:73)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1897)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:348)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:224)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155)
at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menu_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(menu_jsp.java:108)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menu_jsp._jspService(menu_jsp.java:77)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menu_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(menu_jsp.java:186)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menu_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(menu_jsp.java:122)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menu_jsp._jspService(menu_jsp.java:77)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.addressList_jsp._jspService(addressList_jsp.java:137)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:172)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 17, 2014 10:25:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
```

If I use below code

```
Query query =   session.getNamedQuery("getMenus");
query=query.setParameter(0, 1);
query=query.setParameter(1, "jigar");
List<Menu> list = query.list();
```

it works fine and returns proper result.

But when I pass this in @Loader for collection, it can't find positional parameters. However, if I use single positional parameter i.e. ? then it works there too, as submenus are mapped by parent and it takes parent value as positional parameter. but for further positional parameters, it doesn't work.

Comment: You *cannot add @ Loader annotation on @ OneToMany mapping. It is only applicable for Class & Collections*. Have a look at my answer. I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Change your code from**

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
              name="submenus", 
              query="select * from menu where parent = ? ",
              resultClass=Menu.class)
@Table(name="menu", catalog="test")
public class Menu implements Serializable{
```

**to**

```
@NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery(
                  name="submenus", 
                  query="select * from menu where parent = :parentName and menu_item_id = :menuItemId",
                  resultClass=Menu.class)
})
@Entity
@Table(name="menu", catalog="test")
public class Menu implements Serializable{
```

**Remove @Loader annotation from**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Loader(namedQuery = "submenus")
private List<Menu> submenus;
```

**& place it on top of Menu class as**

```
@NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery(
                  name="submenus", 
                  query="select * from menu where parent = :parentName and menu_item_id = :menuItemId",
                  resultClass=Menu.class)
})
@Loader(namedQuery = "submenus")
@Entity
@Table(name="menu", catalog="test")
public class Menu implements Serializable{
```

*Bcoz @Loader annotation is only applicable for Class & Collections, not for Association like @OneToMany, etc.*

**Call your named native query as**

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("submenus");
query.setParameter("parentName", "Whatever u want");
query.setParameter("menuItemId", "Whatever u want");

//or
//if ur query is like this
//select * from menu where parent = ? and menu_item_id = ?
query.setParameter(1, "Whatever u want");
query.setParameter(2, "Whatever u want");
```

Also have a look at

1. [@Loader on @OneTOMany doesn't work](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1004617).
2. [Hibernate Named Query (XML Mapping)](http://kruders.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-xml-mapping/)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @OO7. It makes quite clear to me.. Just to add some more, Can you explain how we can set positional parameters in case of multiple positional parameters. i.e. if my query is like this   select * from menu where parent = :parent_Name and menu_item_id=?

Comment: You can call `query.setParameter("parent_Name ", "Whatever u want");` multiple time passing different parameters. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again @OO7, after going through the link you provided, I have moved sql query to hibernate configuration file. Now it fetches the submenu list if I use static parameters. but when I use positional parameters or named parameters, it doesn't set it using query.setParameter in dao. I guess this query will be called when submenus will be accessed first time as they are lazily loaded. at that time, where can we set the parameters? in POJO? or in DAO? and how?

Comment: How did you set named or positional parameters in XML ? Can u updated ur question with that code snippet ? So that I can get idea what exactly u r doing ? Have u tried with annotations ?

Comment: R u using `named SQL query` or `native SQL query` in XML mapping ? I think there is something wrong in ur XML file. **Have a look the link added in my answer**. I have updated my answer.

Comment: If i use the query like this Query query =   session.getNamedQuery("getMenus");
        query=query.setParameter(0, 1);
        query=query.setParameter(1, "jigar");

Comment: **I think index of positional parameter starts with 1 not with 0.** Try with this change & let me know will it works.

Answer (score 1):

Named queries support multiple parameters, but `@Loader` supports only one and other query parameters won't be replaced. The parameters can't be set globally on session (like in case of `@Filter`), but only per instance of the named query.

When you use `@NamedQuery` or `@NamedNativeQuery` from `@Loader` you can use only one parameter (regardless of its type, positional/named) which will be replaced with `Serializable` id of queried entity.

```
    if ( query.hasNamedParameters() ) {
        query.setParameter( query.getNamedParameters()[0], id, persister.getIdentifierType() );
    }
    else {
        query.setParameter( 0, id, persister.getIdentifierType() );
    }
```

see [org.hibernate.persister.entity.NamedQueryLoader#load(Serializable, Object, SessionImplementor)](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d0c2c31ab7217da32eee2a82457eb321a3aebbaa/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/persister/entity/NamedQueryLoader.java#L60)